# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type in AngularJs and asp.net mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Well I know it is well known error. There are lots of questions asked here. But after going through few questions I am not able to solve my problem I am getting this error my website.

This is my error 
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type

My Controller Code is

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get(int currentPage, int recordsPerPage)
        {
            var pageNumber = currentPage;
            var pageSize = recordsPerPage;
            var begin = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;

            var totalNumberOfRecords = db.Products.Count();
            var productlist = db.Products.OrderBy(r => r.ProductID).Skip(begin).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            //var productlist = db.Products.ToList();
            var product = new  { Product = productlist, TotalRecords = totalNumberOfRecords };

           return Json(new  { Products = productlist, RecordCount = totalNumberOfRecords }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
        }
```

My Angular Controller Code is this

```
   function GetProducts() {

        var productResult = productService.getProduct($scope.currentPage, $scope.recordsPerPage);
        productResult.then(function (result) {
            console.log("d",data);
            if (result.data != '' || result.data != null) {

                if (result.data != null || result.data != '') {
                    $scope.Products = result.data;
                }
                else if (result.data = 0) {
                    $scope.message = "No Product Found"

                }
            }

        });
    };
```

And Angular Service code is this

```
  this.getProduct = function (currentPage, recordsPerPage) {
        return $http.get('/Home/Get?currentPage=' + currentPage + '&recordsPerPage=' + recordsPerPage);
       // return $http.get('/Home/Get');
    };
```

I am missing something but I am unable to get that. Any expert please help me in this.. I spend my whole night with this error. I try every solution of stackoverflow which I read but nothing works for me

Here is My Model

```
namespace StylesStore.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Product
    {
        public Product()
        {
            this.Carts = new HashSet<Cart>();
            this.OrdersDetails = new HashSet<OrdersDetail>();
        }

        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SKU { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> VendorProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SupplierID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CategoryID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> QuantityPerUnit { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> MSRP { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AvailableSize { get; set; }
        public string AvailableColor { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Size { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Discount { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> UnitWeight { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> UnitsInStock { get; set; }
        public string UnitsInOrder { get; set; }
        public string Picture1 { get; set; }
        public string Picture2 { get; set; }
        public string Picture3 { get; set; }
        public string Picture4 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> ShippingCharges { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> InStock { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CatID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> wieght { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> totalview { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Disable { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> EntryDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrdersDetail> OrdersDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is you model for `Product`? Does it contain a property which is a complex object and contains a property `Product` (is a circular reference)?

Comment: I am using db first procedure

Comment: That not relevant. You need to show your models.

Comment: I added model please see

Comment: You have a lot of navigation properties (`Category`, `Supplier`, `ICollection<Cart>` and `ICollection<OrdersDetail>`) some of which must contain references back to `Product`. You need to send a collection of anonymous objects containing just the properties you need in the view

Comment: ok means I have to create a different view model for this

Comment: Not necessarily. You can just use an anonymous object - `var data = productlist.Select(x => new { ProductID = x.ProductID, SKU = x.SKU, etc }); return Json(new  { Products = data, ...);` - just include only those properties you need in the view. Currently your sending much more data across the wire than is necessary

Answer (score 0):

You should not serialize your entity objects. Your entity objects have virtual navigation properties which are detected by JsonSerializer. JsonSerializer thinks they are embedded properties of that object and tries to serialize them too. and this goes on. serializer finds itself trying to serialize all database. this is why your error occurs.

You should either mark fields that need to be serialized or use DTO's to serialize objects.

Note: you can use AutoMapper to map objects between Entity and DTO